# Loading data from SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-listview

I have a chatting application that saves the messages in a `Sqlite` database. I need to load all messages for each chat when clicked by user and show them in `ListView` in an activity. So i was wondering how to do this ? 
I thought of a couple of ways to do that

**First option:** get the data from database (messages i.e. Strings) before opening the messaging screen for the user in arrays and pass them through the intent when starting the messaging activity and then show the messages on onCreate() method.

**Second Option:** get the data (messages i.e. Strings) from database when activity is being created and show them.

**Third option:** Saving Persistent State according to `Sqlite`

Any other ideas are appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: try to making it in background thread with progress bar in the activity that will display the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 2nd option.just send the unique chat id to the `chat screen` and load all the messages of that chat from database in `oncreate()` method and then bind all messages to the `listview.`

Comment: I will give it a try. But what if loading the messages at `onCreate()` takes time ? maybe a progress bar as suggested by @mohammed momn would be helpful here.

Comment: not progress bar show dialog box instead, and display some message and fetching messages from database couldnt take too much time, it will be in milli seconds.

Comment: Loaded in a perfect way without the need for threads. but i will look if a thread is needed later on when the data is larger in size.

Comment: you will need threads when records are in millions. but since you want to show chat messages , so you can fetch last 50 or 100 messages from database and when user reach to the top then again fetch other records and show to the user.

Answer (score 1):

In Activity, loading sqlite db in others thread, and when it load finish, print it in your list view.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //loading database
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}).start();

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //update listview
    };
};
```

Comment: Sounds like the most reasonable way to load them in a `thread` at the `onCreate()`. I will give it a try and get back with the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to load them when you open the Activity, but I wouldn't load all messages but just the last X items. Most users won't scroll up to older messages 99% of the times.

You could for example load the last 10 messages and then (if the users make scroll up) load the other messages.

Luck!!

Comment: Sounds logical especially that it wont take time to select the last X messages, prepare them, and set up the `listview`